# Basic Python list split

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering how I could split the following list of strings:

Given list:

l = `["George Smith", "Mark Johnson", "Cordell Theodore", "Maria Satterfield", "Johnson Cadence"]`

Result required:

l1 = `["George", "Mark", "Cordell", "Maria", "Johnson"]`

l2 = `["Smith", "Johnson", "Theodore", "Satterfield", "Cadence"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. This answer involves use of list comprehension (look it up if you aren't already familiar with the syntax):

```
l = ["George Smith", "Mark Johnson", "Cordell Theodore", "Maria Satterfield", "Johnson Cadence"]
l1 = [x.split()[0] for x in l]
print(l1)
l2 = [x.split()[1] for x in l]
print(l2)

## ['George', 'Mark', 'Cordell', 'Maria', 'Johnson']
## ['Smith', 'Johnson', 'Theodore', 'Satterfield', 'Cadence']
```